# WPDB query suddenly not working

Tags: functions, wpdb

I have a function that contains a wpdb query. It's supposed to get the image alt text, based on the url of the image. This is the function:

```
// retrieves the attachment alt from the file URL
function get_image_alt_from_url($image_url) {
  global $wpdb;
  $id = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='%s';", $image_url ));
  if ($id) {
    return get_post_meta($id[0], '_wp_attachment_image_alt', TRUE);
  }
  return false;
}
```

It used to work, but now it returns false every time. Upon debugging the function, I found that the `$id` variable is null.

I wonder if this has anything to do with upgrading PHP to 8.0, and if so, how to get around it. It still works on my local site, so I doubt it's related to a wp core update.

WordPress: 6.2.2
PHP: 8.0
Hosted on Kinsta

Thank you so much for your help,

Jill

Comment: [`WPDB::get_col()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_col/) should *always* return an array, not `null`, even if you pass it `null` as a query. *Where* in the code snippet were you testing `$id` and finding it `null`?

Comment: Even if the issue gets fixed, it's still not best practice. Is there a reason you're interacting with the DB directly? It's harmless now, but it's good practice to always look for a better solution if the one you have is interacting with the database directly.

You can get the picture ID from it's URL via `$id = attachment_url_to_postid($image_url);`. Once you have that, you can get it's alt via `$alt = get_post_meta($id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', TRUE);`

Comment: @alex That's a good point, and it might be worth making it into an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @PatJ Thank you, I was thinking I'm not actually solving the problem, just suggesting a different approach, but I added an answer where I tried to do both.

Comment: Sometimes the answer is literally "Do it a different way".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only interact with the DB via WP, not directly. It's not a big deal in your case because you just want to see a value, but you'll be more aligned with the best practices if you go in trying to solve a problem with $wpdb as a last resort.
In your case, you can try this :

```
$id = attachment_url_to_postid($image_url);
$alt = get_post_meta($id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', TRUE);
```

We'll first get the Post ID from the attachment URL, and then find the alt from that ID. This will do what you want without $wpdb.

That said, let's try and debug your original problem too!

As @PatJ said, `WPDB::get_col()` never returns null, so something's wrong.
Turn on your debug like this :

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

The first line enables debugging mode, the second line ensures that debug messages are logged to a wp-content/debug.log file, and the third line prevents debug messages from being displayed on the site.

Run it again. Was an error logged? If not, run this :

`echo $wpdb->last_error;`

Also, after your get_col line, print the last query using the $wpdb->last_query command. This can help you make sure the query is as expected :

`echo $wpdb->last_query;`

Of course, check the image URL too - maybe it's not correct, or it's not in the database. It shouldn't return null, but worth checking.

Also, it's possible that the issue is not with your $wpdb->get_col() line but the get_post_meta() line. You can debug this by checking what it returns when you give it a known post ID and '_wp_attachment_image_alt' as the meta key.

Comment: Thanks so much for the thorough reply. This is actually what I ended up doing (I was rushed to fix this), but I appreciate the addition of the debugging tips. At some point I'll have to roll everything back and follow your debugging instructions, so I can follow up on why it didn't work...